# Meta Quest2/3 Unity SDK - How to get battery level info

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, quest

I'm wondering if anyone here has experience or insights into how I can retrieve the battery level of the headset and controllers programmatically?

I've looked through the Oculus documentation and various forums, but I haven't found a clear solution yet. If anyone has tackled this before or has any pointers on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

SystemInfo.batteryLevel returns a good value on the Quest 3 - I haven't tested it on the Quest 2 but I would assume that it would do the same.

As for the controllers, I have looked and I cannot find a solution either. Additionally, even though the controllers do report a battery level to the Meta Quest app, these values are extremely coarse. I think you're out of luck on that front.